# LESS Variable Interpolation

Tags: less

I'm trying to simplify my CSS even further than I already have with LESS by using functions and variable interpolation. I was completely unaware of variable interpolation until I took a look at Hover.css' less files which is no surprise as to why I'm screwing up now.

I'm working on Reddit to make a flair system and I am encountering problems using variable interpolation.

I am currently using the below as a test:

```
.flair.flair-one { color: red; }
.flair.flair-two { color: green; }
.flair.flair-three { color: blue; }

.custom(@a; @b; @c) {
  &::before { .flair.flair-@{a}; }
  .flair.flair-@{b};
  &::after { .flair.flair-@{c}; }
}

.this-flair {
  .custom(one; two; three);
}
```

That's the basic structure of what I'm doing. While testing in online compilers, `.this-flair` isn't working.

Is someone able to tell me what I can do to resolve this? I'm looking through the LESS functions and it appears as though this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: I don't think interpolation works for mixin calls.

Comment: As SLaks has already said, I don't think this would work. Depending on your needs, you can try out using rulesets and selector formation like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986070/use-function-mixin-in-less-selector/25986681#25986681).

Comment: @Harry That would end up being more complicated and longer than what I currently have.

Comment: @Spedwards: I didn't mean to pass the entire ruleset in every call. You can assign the ruleset to a variable (like the base classes in your code) and then just pass that around. Having said that, only you would know how well it fits your real scenario :)

Comment: @Harry, that's similar to what I have though still larger.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments above you can't interpolate either mixin or function calls. In a quick glance, parametric mixins (with pattern matching) are what you actually need to use for such snippets:

```
.flair-flair(one)   {color: red}
.flair-flair(two)   {color: green}
.flair-flair(three) {color: blue}

.custom(@a, @b, @c) {
    .flair-flair(@b);
    &::before {.flair-flair(@a)}
    &::after  {.flair-flair(@c)}
}

.this-flair {
    .custom(one, two, three);
}
```

Comment: Nice option. Something tells me that OP could be trying to re-use this mixin for multiple other *-one, *-two selectors though.

Comment: @Harry, probably. But I'm pretty sure if he shows that bigger use-case I will be able to craft a mixin-based equivalent for it (the only show-stopper could be some-verbosity/not-very-DRY code).