# How to generate less syntax in less?

Tags: less

I want to generate a common class which include all the styles of button, it will look like this

```
 .commonButton {
      .button1;
      .button2;
      .button3;
      .
      .button15;
  }
```

So how to generate this syntax in less ? What I have tried is like this

```
.loopingClass(@index) when (@index > 0) {   
  .button@{index}; // this will give syntax error
  .loopingClass(@index - 1);
};
.loopingClass(15);
```

Comment: But what exactly is the point of creating a common button class with all properties? I am asking this because if you set multiple colors and combine them into one class it is of no use. Can you show your actual use case?

Comment: Yes, i have a scenario in which I need all the properties of all buttons in a common Class.

Comment: I think your case is a XY problem mate. Probably you are trying to fix it the wrong way.

Comment: Coming to the actual point, you cannot invoke a mixin using interpolation. You would find a workaround in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387231/less-variable-interpolation) but I don't think it would be all that useful for your case either.

Comment: My guess is that you actually need a common class for all buttons since `color: blue` would overwrite `color: white` ... and that makes no sense. If I'm right, you could add an extra class to each button or just use the button tag selector.

Comment: You're doing CSS wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just create 1 class for all common properties for all buttons and then a series of separate classes that just overide the differentiated features? e.g.

```
.white {color: white;}
.blue {color: blue;}
.green {color: green;}
.ctralign {text-align: center;}
```

And so on. And then your html would be as:

```
<img class="button white ctralign"...
```